# Empty Cell to early in While Wend

Tags: excel, vba, while-loop

After the second round of my code the while wend loop stops because the field seems empty, even if I look after it in the watch window. But the Excel table is full with stuff from Cells 1:1 to 12:92...

```
    x = 1
    y = 2
    While Cells(x & 1) <> ""
        If Cells(x & 1) = cmb_spalte Then
            While Cells(x & y) <> ""
                If Cells(x & y) = txt_suchwert Then
                    meineDatei.WriteLine (Range("C" & y) & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & Range("G" & y) & 
                    vbTab & vbTab & Range("K" & y))
                    y = y + 1
                End If
            Wend
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Wend
```

Comment: `Cells(x & 1)` and `Cells(x & y)` don't make sense. `Cells` is normally used with two arguments, the row and column numbers.

Comment: Side note: `While...Wend` is deprecated.

Comment: I think you want `,` instead of `&`?

Comment: It looks like you are building your own search function instead of using `Range.Find`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.Find